# How to go to another screen in top tab navigation in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to go out of top tab navigation but it unable to navigate. It's giving error The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"LoginPage"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'LoginPage'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

I use nesting navigation also but not work. My Screens are below

Top tab navigation screen

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import ProfileData from './profiledata';
import ProfileLikeData from './profilelikedata';
import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';


const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
 return (
   <NavigationContainer>
     <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
       tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => {
         let iconName;
         let size;

         if (route.name === 'Data') {
           iconName = focused
             ? 'nav-icon-grid'
             : 'nav-icon-grid';
           size = focused
           ? 25
           : 25; 
         } else if (route.name === 'Like') {
           iconName = focused ? 'heart' : 'heart';
           size = focused
           ? 20
           : 20; 
         }
         return <Fontisto name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
       },
     })}
       tabBarOptions={{
         activeTintColor: '#d40786',
         inactiveTintColor: 'white',
         showIcon:true,
         showLabel:false,
         indicatorStyle: {
           width: 0, height: 0, elevation: 0,      
         },
         tabStyle: { width: wp('52%'),borderRightWidth:1,borderColor:'white' },
         style: { backgroundColor:'trasparent',borderTopWidth:0.5,borderColor:'white',paddingBottom:5 },
       }}
     >
       <Tab.Screen name="Data" component={ProfileData} />
       <Tab.Screen name="Like" component={ProfileLikeData} />
     </Tab.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
 );
}
```

profiledata.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text,ImageBackground,TouchableOpacity,Image } from 'react-native';
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import { RFPercentage, RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';

export default class ProfileData extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          videos:[],
          loginid:'',
          paused:true,
        };
      }

    static navigationOptions = {
      headerShown: false,
    };

   

 
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatGrid
          data={this.state.videos}
          spacing={0}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigate('LoginPage')} style={{flex:1}}>
            // some data
            </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    // paddingHorizontal:wp('2%'),
    backgroundColor:'black',
    height: hp('100%'),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create another stack that has your login screen or add the login screen in the tab navigator.
for the first do something like this in your app.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';  //Just import the login screen

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthStackScreen = () => (
  <AuthStack.Navigator>
    <AuthStack.Screen
      name="LoginPage"
      component={LoginScreen}
    />
  </AuthStack.Navigator>
);

//Then in your profiledata.js;

<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigate('LoginPage')} style={{flex:1}}>
            // some data
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And for the second option just add the login screen in your tab navigator;

```
<Tab.Screen name="Data" component={ProfileData} />
<Tab.Screen name="Like" component={ProfileLikeData} />
<Tab.Screen name="LoginPage" component={LoginScreen} /> //Don't forget to import it
```